# добавление кастомной кнопки на страницу редактирования объекта в django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Собственно говоря в заголовке вся суть вопроса. У меня есть функция, которая принимает объект модели который сейчас редактируется и что-то с ним делает. Как сделать так, чтобы во время редактирования объекта модели в джанго админ там была кнопка для вызова этой функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартной админке такого функционала не предусмотрено. Только если перепиливать саму админку.